# Find the convex hull around a set of polygons?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.4 with PostGIS 2.1. I have a table with the following columns:

```
    Column    |          Type                 
--------------+------------------------
 ogc_fid      | integer                
 wkb_geometry | geometry(Polygon,4326) 
 plot_id      | integer               
 org          | character varying
```

I want to get all the polygons relating to a particular organisation, draw the convex hull around them, then calculate the area of that convex hull.

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT
 SUM(ST_AREA(ST_CONCAVEHULL(wkb_geometry, 0.1)::geography)) AS area
 FROM mytable
 WHERE org='myorg'
```

But it seems to be first finding the convex hull of each individual polygon, then adding together the areas. This is not what I want.

How can I edit this query to *first* find the convex hull of the entire polygon set, and only then calculate the area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a union call and also 0.1 is pretty low for a concave hull, try something like 0.7. (that is really the shrink parameter so 0.1 would be like target to 10% of convexhull area.  The smaller the value the longer the processing and more likely you'll run into invalid geometry)

```
SELECT
  SUM(ST_AREA(ST_CONCAVEHULL(ST_Union(wkb_geometry), 0.7)::geography)) AS area
FROM mytable
WHERE org='myorg';
```

Comment: I suppose that there is only one concave hull because of UNION so SUM is unnecessary, but it does not make any harm.

Comment: correct you can get rid of the sum.  Also did you want ST_ConcaveHull or ST_ConvexHull?  ST_ConvexHull is a much faster process.